# Google Spreadsheet Last X Rows

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using charts in Google Spreadsheet to plot the last 90 days of data. However, when adding new data it's outside the charts currently selected range of A1:A90. Is there a function I can use to select the last 90 rows of data in a column of a Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create a new sheet and use the `QUERY` function to get the last 90 rows:

- If column A is unique and sortable, you simply sort your data in reverse order and take the top 90 rows, and then reverse sort it again:

  `=SORT(QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z,"order by A desc limit 90"),1,1)`
- If that is not the case, then you need to calculate the offset by finding the last row and subtracting 90 from it, and then query the data to return 90 rows starting from that offset:

  `=QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z,"limit 90 offset "&(COUNT(Sheet1!A:A)-90))`

You can then use this sheet to generate your chart.

Comment: Great answer. A small improvement - if your column can have less that 90 rows, then the second formula can be updated to: `=QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z,"limit 90 offset "&(MAX(COUNT(Sheet1!A:A)-90), 0)))`

Comment: Excellent answer, it helped me out today! I ended up used a slightly modified version  that can handle non-numeric data too. The `COUNT()` method only accepts numeric data, but if you change it to `COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A, "<>")` it will work with any data. So my version is:

`=QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z,"limit 90 offset "&(MAX(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,"<>")-90)))`

Also, for the Swedish version of Google Sheets, you need to change commas to semi-commas (, -> ;). So the actual version I use is:

`=QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z;"limit 90 offset "&(MAX(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A;"<>")-90)))`

Answer (score 0):

No to my best knowledge, unless you write own google spreadsheet script and use ranges. Script can programatically feed chart with data by

- opening Spreadsheet & Sheet
- getting data
- isolating range, e.g. last 90 rows
- feeding with that range the chart component

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `SORTN` function to achieve the required result if one or more of your columns are sortable.

In the example below the last 90 rows are listed in descending order with the first sort reverse sorting them back to ascending order:

```
SORT(SORTN(Sheet1!A:Z,90,0,1,0),1,1)
```

If you wish to list the last 90 rows after filtering on a particular attribute you can combine the above with a filter function:

```
SORT(SORTN(FILTER(Sheet1!A:Z,filter to be applied),90,0,1,0),1,1)
```

If required you can also list the second last 90 records (91 to 180 from last) by applying two `SORTN` functions as follows:

```
SORTN(SORTN(Sheet1!A:Z,180,0,1,0),90,0,1,1)
```